# Disable CefSharp on screen keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a C# CefSharp winforms app and I was wondering if there is a way to disable the built in on screen keyboard behaviour when running on a Windows 10 device with a touch screen, tablet mode enabled and the "touch-events" command line argument set to "enabled". Currently the Onscreen keyboard is launched when a text box on a web page is selected. Can this be disabled? I have tried setting the focus listener to null and have looked through the docs but can not see anything obvious.

Comment: https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: See if you can disable it in Chrome first, if you cannot then you won't be able to in CefSharp